# Arranging data in columns using awk

Tags: python, awk, text-processing

I have a data 300 output `.out` files from which I need to obtain data.
Generally the data is stored in them as:

```
PROPERTY 1:   1234
lines 
of 
unimportant text
PROPERTY 2: 1334
lines 
of 
unimportant text
PROPERTY 3: 1237
.
.
.
PROPERTY N: 7592
```

I have 300 such files.

I want to extract the data from these files and arrange them into neat columns. a column for all data points for PROPERTY 1, one column for PROPERTY 2,..., one column for PROPERTY N. The end goal is to use python and pandas to process the data further.

I am using awk to extract this data.

I have two methods of doing this, but each has a problem.
Method one:
`awk '/PROPERTY 1/{p1=$NF; } /PROPERTY 2/{p2=$NF} /PROPERTY 3/... {pn=$NF; print p1, p2, p3,...}' *.out`
This method has two problems:

I can extract individual data points and store them into files, however, this is a long program.
Also, in the event that PROPERTY 1 and PROPERTY 2 have their positions flipped, this code will give a faulty output ie PROPERTY 1 from outputfile1.out will show up on line 2, instead of line 1. How do I make it so that this output is not faulty?

The second method I have is simply outputting them into distinct files and joining them together using python. Is there a way to pick up a column from file1 and pasting it right beside the column in file 2 using awk?

Sample input file:

first.out:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
PROPERTY 1:    1234

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit
PROPERTY 2:    9800

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.

PROPERTY 4:   823586

On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain.

PROPERTY 3:   328497
.
.
.
```

second.out:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
PROPERTY 1:    1

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit
PROPERTY 2:    2

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.

PROPERTY 3:   3

On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain.

PROPERTY 4:   4
.
.
.
```

Each file will have all properties.

Expected output file:
data.txt

```
1234  9800  823586  328497 ...
1  2  3  4 
.
.
.
```

I am trying to optimize my code and awk seems to blazing fast. Any advice you have would be appreciated!!

Comment: Could you please do add more clear your sample output in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Your goal is to have a single `pandas.DataFrame` with PROPERTY i on column i, and every row is one value for each one of the 300 files?

Comment: yes @crissal, that is the goal

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added one example input file, and one example output file

Comment: Why did you tag this with awk when "The end goal is to use python and pandas"? If the end goal is to use python then just use python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for ENDFILE and assuming you have a specific subset of PROPERTY tags you want to print, not all of which are present in every file (your posted examples aren't clear on that or if the properties all REALLY start with PROPERTY, etc.):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numTags = split("PROPERTY 1,PROPERTY 2,PROPERTY 3,PROPERTY 4",tags,/,/)
}
{
    tag = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    f[tag] = $NF
}
ENDFILE {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = f[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete f
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk first second
1234 9800 328497 823586
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a line by line analysis:

```py
import re

RE_PROPERTY = re.compile(r"^PROPERTY\s*([0-9]+)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*\n$")

columns = {}

with open("data.out", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m = RE_PROPERTY.match(line)
        if m:
            key = f"PROPERTY {m.group(1)}"
            value = m.group(2)
            col = columns.setdefault(key, [])
            col.append(value)

print(columns)
```